# Hiding a element using media query

Tags: media-queries

I'm trying to use a media query to hide the social media icon bar when the screen gets to a smaller size. I have used a media shown below, which doesn't seem to work.  I'm using bootstrap to build my website if that helps.

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .icon-bar {
    display: none;
  }
}



.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}


.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

 HTML CODE 



    <div class="icon-bar">
          <a href="https://facebook.com/spartansafety" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/spartansafety01?lang=en" target="_blank" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spartansafety/" target="_blank" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/spartan-safety-limted-78a585156/" target="_blank" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: please add your html content

Comment: @saurabhMistry Yes i'm using bootstrap and I just added the code

Comment: which version of bootstrap are u using ?

Comment: @saurabhMistry version 4

Comment: you code doesnt seem to be properly formanteed use CTRL+M so that we can view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap 4, then no need to use custom media query , use bootstrap 4 class

> d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none to display only on medium and large screen

```
<div class="icon-bar">
      <a href="https://facebook.com/spartansafety" target="_blank" class="facebook d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/spartansafety01?lang=en" target="_blank" class="twitter d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spartansafety/" target="_blank" class="instagram d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/spartan-safety-limted-78a585156/" target="_blank" class="linkedin d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none">
```

you can read more here : http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: @VictorJohnson , please accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try placing all your media queries at the bottom of the code file order by size where smallest is at the bottom